# \shortmonthname for German in datetime

Tags: datetime, german

It seems that if you set your document to `ngerman`, `datetime` currently only supports abbreviated names for the days of the week (Mo, Di, Mi …), but not for month names (Jan, Feb, Mär …). Is there anything I can put in the preamble of my `.tex` file to get the three-letter abbreviations for month names in German?

Answer (score 5):

In analogy to what it says in the documentation and the file `dt-ngerman.def`, the code for getting the abbreviated month names should look about like this:

```
\makeatletter
\providecommand{\shortmonthnamengerman}[1][\month]{%
\@orgargctr=#1\relax
\ifcase\@orgargctr
\PackageError{datetime}{Invalid Month number \the\@orgargctr}{%
Month numbers should go from 1 to 12}%
\or Jan%
\or Feb%
\or M\"ar%
\or Apr%
\or Mai%
\or Jun%
\or Jul%
\or Aug%
\or Sep%
\or Okt%
\or Nov%
\or Dez%
\else
\PackageError{datetime}{Invalid Month number \the\@orgargctr}{%
Month numbers should go from 1 to 12}%
\fi}%
\let\shortmonthnamengerman\shortmonthnamengerman
\makeatother
```

It'd be nice if this list could be added to the `datetime` package sometime.

---

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{datetime}

% Customizing datetime
\makeatletter
\providecommand{\shortmonthnamengerman}[1][\month]{
\@orgargctr=#1\relax
\ifcase\@orgargctr
\PackageError{datetime}{Invalid Month number \the\@orgargctr}{Month numbers should go from 1 to 12}
\or Jan
\or Feb
\or M\"ar
\or Apr
\or Mai
\or Jun
\or Jul
\or Aug
\or Sep
\or Okt
\or Nov
\or Dez
\else
\PackageError{datetime}{Invalid Month number \the\@orgargctr}{Month numbers should go from 1 to 12}
\fi}
\let\shortmonthnamengerman\shortmonthnamengerman
\makeatother

\newdateformat{mladate}{\the\day~\shortmonthname[\the\month]~\the\year}

\begin{document}

\today

\mladate\today

\ddmmyyyydate\today

\end{document}
```

[image: Date formats demonstration]

Comment: I have made a danish brrevation list and hope that someone will add it to the datetime package, as I don't know how to do it.

Comment: The code is as follows: \makeatletter
\providecommand{\shortmonthnamedanish}[1][\month]{%
\@orgargctr=#1\relax
\ifcase\@orgargctr
\PackageError{datetime}{Invalid Month number \the\@orgargctr}{%
Month numbers should go from 1 to 12}%
\or Jan.%
\or Feb.%
\or Mar.%
\or Apr.%
\or Maj%
\or Jun.%
\or Jul.%
\or Aug.%
\or Sep.%
\or Okt.%
\or Nov.%
\or Dec.%
\else
\PackageError{datetime}{Invalid Month number \the\@orgargctr}{%
Month numbers should go from 1 to 12}%
\fi}%
\let\shortmonthnamengerman\shortmonthnamengerman
\makeatother